# ERRO: Connection timed out (110) >> shoutCast

Tags: php

Boa noite.
Estou tendo um problema com um código de conexão de uma radio shoutCast.
No localhost: 127.0.0.1/tributus/server/on.php ele retornar a musica que esta passando normal, já hospedado ele retorna como um erro de conexão:

Connection timed out (110)

```
<?php
    $ip = "170.75.145.250"; 
    $port = "17652";
    $conexao = @fsockopen($ip,$port,$errno,$errstr,1); 

    if (!$conexao) {
        echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
    } else {
        fputs($conexao, "GET /7.html HTTP/1.0\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla\r\n\r\n");

        while (!feof($conexao)) {
            $dados = fgets($conexao);
        }

        $dados = str_replace('</body></html>', "", $dados);
        $resultado = explode(',', $dados);
        echo($resultado[6]);
    }
?>
```

Alguém tem ou já viu uma solução para essa conexão?

Answer (score 0):

Às vezes o servidor remoto demora a responder e geralmente há um tempo limite (~30s, em geral) para que o seja retornado até o socket de rede fechar fechar e retornar um erro de tempo de conexão esgotado (timeout).
Não estou muito certo sobre, testando aqui o seu server do shoutcast responde rapidamente. No entanto, no seu código, você definiu para o 5º parâmetro de fsockopen() o timeout de 1 segundo. Talvez aí está o erro, você deveria ter algo mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php 

define('TIMEOUT', 30);

$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, TIMEOUT);
```

Também, já ouvi casos que algumas hospedagem não liberam portas para conexão com shoutcast, mas não estou certo se é o seu caso, até porque outro erro é que retornaria, ao invés de conexão expirada. Mas em todo caso...